# extract value between - and > with uncertain length in excel using python and the days & times into another list

Tags: python, excel

I have a column in an excel file like this:

column B

195-36>[14/07 09:44:35]+195-34>[14/07 09:44:35]

195-35>[14/07 09:44:35]+195-65>[14/07 09:44:35]+195-33>[14/07 09:44:35]

195-25>[14/07 09:44:35]+195-15>[14/07 09:44:35]+195-35>[14/07 09:44:35]

173-21>[14/07 14:19:30]+173-1>[14/07 14:19:30]+173-7>[14/07 14:19:30]

174-55>[14/07 09:46:53]

The length is different in each cell and i want to extract values between - and > .
The output will be 36,34,35,65,33,25,15,35,21,1,7,55 in a list.
thank you very much.

As an update for the question, what if i want to extract the days and times into another list as shown :

14/07 09:44:35,14/07 09:44:35,14/07 09:44:35,14/07 09:44:35,14/07 09:44:35,14/07 09:44:35,14/07 09:44:35,14/07 09:44:35,14/07 14:19:30,14/07 14:19:30,14/07 14:19:30,14/07 09:46:53

thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using a regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression that isolates digits between the two characters '-' and '>'.

Let's assume you have the data from the spreadsheet as a list of strings:

```
import re

data = [
    '195-36>[14/07 09:44:351+195-34>[14/07 09:44:351',
    '195-35>[14/07 09:44:35]+195-65>(14/07 09:44:35]+195-33>[14/07 09:44:35]',
    '195-25>[14/07 09:44:351+195-15>{14/07 09:44:35]+195-35>[14/07 09:44:35]',
    '173-21>(14/07 14:19:30]+173-1>(14/07 14:19:30]+173-7>14/07 14:19:30]',
    '174-55> 14/07 09:46:531'
]

values = []
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=-)\d+?(?=>)')
for datum in data:
    values.extend(map(int, pattern.findall(datum)))
print(values)
```

**Output:**

```
[36, 34, 35, 65, 33, 25, 15, 35, 21, 1, 7, 55]
```

Answer (score -1):

RegExp is good at it.

```py
import re
input_text = """
195-36>\[14/07 09:44:35\]+195-34>\[14/07 09:44:35\] 
195-35>\[14/07 09:44:35\]+195-65>\[14/07 09:44:35\]+195-33>\[14/07 09:44:35\]
195-25>\[14/07 09:44:35\]+195-15>\[14/07 09:44:35\]+195-35>\[14/07 09:44:35\]
173-21>\[14/07 14:19:30\]+173-1>\[14/07 14:19:30\]+173-7>\[14/07 14:19:30\]
174-55>\[14/07 09:46:53\]
"""
pattern = r"-(\d+)>"
result = re.findall(pattern, input_text)
print(result)
print(list(map(int, result)))
```

Output is as blow:

> ['36', '34', '35', '65', '33', '25', '15', '35', '21', '1', '7', '55']

> [36, 34, 35, 65, 33, 25, 15, 35, 21, 1, 7, 55]

Comment: This does not produce the required output. Also, why all the backslashes?

Comment: The result of `re` is `String`. It is easy to get `int`. Please try updated code.